# importing flask models into python console in a scalable architecture

Tags: python, flask, scalable

i have have the following folder structure for a simple flask-app.

[image: Folder structure]

with a one-page structure i was able to import models in python console, but since i changed the structure to a scalable model, i cant seem to find a way to import models into my python console, i get this error.

**RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context**

is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: Did you try from `app.catalog.models import ModelName` ?

Comment: yes kiran, they get imported without any issues, but when i create an instance of a table (class), it throws the above said error...

Comment: Can you share your code that you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running in an application context. Use the [`flask shell`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/cli/) command to set this up for you.

```
FLASK_APP=app flask shell
```

Or set it up manually:

```
>>> from app import app
>>> app.app_context().push()
```